# $(...).find(...).once is not a function Javascript error in Drupal

Tags: 8, javascript

I am getting this error in my console which is causing some other JS items not to work

```
    Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).once is not a function
        at Object.attach (eval at globalEval (jquery.min.js?v=2.2.3:2), <anonymous>:156:44)
        at Object.Drupal.attachBehaviors (drupal.js?v=8.2.5:168)
        at insert (ajax.js?v=8.2.5:1084)
        at Drupal.AjaxCommands.loadEditorsAjax.commands.insert (quickedit.js?v=8.2.5:523)
        at Drupal.Ajax.success (ajax.js?ojj3xe:155)
        at Object.success (ajax.js?v=8.2.5:505)
        at i (jquery.min.js?v=2.2.3:2)
        at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js?v=2.2.3:2)
        at z (jquery.min.js?v=2.2.3:4)
        at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js?v=2.2.3:4)
```

My current Drupal version 8.2.5 is using jquery 2.2.3 so I am not sure what is going on here.

Any ideas? I tried updating jquery to 3.0.0 but that didn't work. Same error.

Comment: The only js change from 8.2.4 to 8.2.5 was related to tests (https://www.drupal.org/node/2830485) so thats probably not your culprit. Are you sure that nothing else changed on your end?

Comment: Are you using the bootstrap theme or a (custom) sub-theme thereof? If so, try excluding `bootstrap.js`.

Comment: @WimMostrey I am using bootstrap and a subtheme of bootstrap. I did update bootstrap as well. I will try to disable bootstrap.js now

Comment: `.once()` is not a jQuery core method. There is probably a plugin that creates the `.once()` method but jQuery core wouldn't be the issue. From your trace it appears to be an issue with an editor AJAX response.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report for the bootstrap theme and needs to be handled in their issue queue

Comment: Ok so we found the issue and it was none of the above or answer below. Google tag manager, that was recently added, was adding a second version of jQuery. The error must've been there since we added tag manager and just didn't notice @WimMostrey

Answer (score 6):

As [suspected](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/225053/find-once-is-not-a-function-drupal-8-2-5?noredirect=1#comment274632_225053) and [confirmed](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/225053/find-once-is-not-a-function-drupal-8-2-5?noredirect=1#comment274633_225053) this is an issue with the bootstrap theme. My advice would be to roll back to the previous working version and open a bug report in their issue queue on drupal.org.

Comment: This is not only a Bootstrap issue. Even [modules can cause it](https://www.drupal.org/project/obfuscate/issues/3172899). The root issue is that a reference to [jQuery Once function](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/444344) is made but no dependency has been declared upon the [`jquery.once` library](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/8.2.x/core/core.libraries.yml#L397) which would include the `once()` code in the Javascript sent to the browser.